# How to start a c# process as another user?

Tags: c#, credentials, runas

I want to start a c# process as another user.

I know the verb "runas" but that only accepts admin user creds.

```
//This code actually meant to restart the appplication with specific args
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
startInfo.Arguments = args;
startInfo.Verb = "runas"; //this line is the question
Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I want to achieve the same thing but also with non-admin users.

Comment: First, you'll need his credit card number.

Comment: AFAIK it is wrong approach to use another application to do the work. AFAIK `runas` will not accept password from your app, it wants it from keyboard.

Comment: Check the [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_System_Security_SecureString_System_String_) overload that accepts a username and a password

Comment: I don't want to specify the password over my app, I want the Windows UAC to do so. Eg. when I Shift+RightClick on an EXE or a shortcut, there's a "Run as different user" option. And that throws up a window that asks for the creds.